# JSONArray not a string exception only when proguard is enabled

Tags: android, json, exception, proguard, obfuscation

`JSONArray.getString(1);` where ["name",null] is the json array, throws a `JSONArray[1] not a string` exception only when proguard is enabled.

Am I missing something in my proguard rules?

Comment: are you using GSON?

Comment: Please post your current proguard rules

Comment: Take a look at this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/58720274/6071729

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: String resCode = signObject.getString("status"); .where status key is an int. Same thing goes for JSONArray or JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these methods:

```
/**
 * Returns the value at {@code index} if it exists, coercing it if
 * necessary. Returns the empty string if no such value exists.
 */
public String optString(int index)
```

or

```
/**
 * Returns the value at {@code index} if it exists, coercing it if
 * necessary. Returns {@code fallback} if no such value exists.
 */
public String optString(int index, String fallback)
```

Seem like does not return `null` for String

Comment: Yes I have, they do work. But the existing project has getString all over.. Switching to optString is the last option.

Comment: By reading the code of `public String getString(int index)`, I can see it throws exceptions if your value is null and currently your input has null value. If you didn't catch the exception everywhere `getString` is used then bugs will keep appearing. Change the method is a hard but safe way