# Gson.toJson returns null [ProGuard issue]

Tags: java, android, json, gson

users Bug report shows `Gson().toJson(obj)` occasionally returns `{}` but for most users it works correct.

i have visited an user who faced the bug and debugged app on his phone and i made `Toast` to show what is sending to server and i saw Toast shows `{}` and also **Records** and **ID** aren't `null`.

here is what i have done.

```
private class ClassA{
        String ID;
        ArrayList<ClassB> Records;

        ClassA(String ID, ArrayList<ClassB> Records) {
            this.ID= ID;
            this.Records= Records;
        }
 }

 private class ClassB {
        int T;
        int F;
        String D;

        ClassB (int T, int F, String D) {
            this.T= T;
            this.F = F;
            this.D= D;
        }

}
```

And here i do serialize object

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA(ID,Records); 
String json = new Gson().toJson(obj);
```

but `new Gson().toJson(obj`) for some users works correct but for some return `{}`

Server database shows some users sent data `{}` but some correct json .after some research i found `new Gson().toJson(obj`) returns `{}`.no webservice problem and no database problem.

**Extra info**

```
ArrayList<ClassB> Records= new ArrayList<>();
Records.add(new ClassB(Integer.valueOf(t.toString()), Integer.valueOf(f.toString()),d.toString()));
ClassA obj = new ClassA(ID,Records); 
String json = new Gson().toJson(obj);
```

**Database**

```
id    | data
----------------
c89   | {"ID":"c89","Records":[{"T":0,"F":0,"D":"2019/04/11 05:48 PM"}]} correct one

c90   | {} bug
```

**Null Input Test**

i did below test and i found problem is beyond the null inputs

```
ArrayList<ClassB> Records= new ArrayList<>();
ClassA obj = new ClassA(null,Records);    
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),new Gson().toJson(obj ),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast shows `{"Records":[]}`.worse than upper condition never happens

And also IDE says

```
if(ID!=null && Records!=null) <= this condition is always true 
ClassA obj = new ClassA(ID,Records);
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

How do i make it to work correct for all users?

**Comments**

> This shouldn't be possible, you need more details on the {} case e.g.
>   is it consistent, is it due to multi-threading, is it a specific JDK
>   version

There isn't any multi-threading phenomena.for example, no `Runnable` no `AsycTask` no `Thread`.it's just a normal fragment which gets data from content provider and create json string.

Suggested solution has same result !

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA(ID,Records); 
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), gson.toJson(obj), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast shows `{}` again.

Comment: try adding `getters` to both of the classes

Comment: This shouldn't be possible, you need more details on the `{}` case e.g. is it consistent, is it due to multi-threading, is it a specific JDK version.

Comment: This looks like something you should post as a bug report to the Gson project. But, they'll ask you to provide more information than you have here. Heads up.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki it's not multi-threading

Comment: @KarolDowbecki reports only shows {} nothing more

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Gson doesn't serialize nulls be default.

Comment: @Jameson i put more

Comment: are you set proguard rules for enteties?

Comment: @AbolhassanPirayeh yea

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis see edit

Comment: Do you use free hosting? Because I had encountered this problem in free hosts before.
The problem was that an invisible character would stick to the end of the output string and Jason would become invalid, this would not always happen but sometimes it would.

Comment: @AbolhassanPirayeh the problem happens in phone before sending to server or host.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names should be written in camelCase, e.g. `Records` should be `records`, `ID` should be `id` and `T`, `F` and `D` should be `t`, `f` and `d` respectively.

Comment: @MCEmperor are you sure it's the problem? because i have to publish and see feedback in production mode .all works correct for me but i am not sure how does it work for users.are you sure?

Comment: The naming convention won't affect whether it works or not, but I do recommend following standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: @MrAF That won't fix the issue, otherwise I would have posted it as answer. However, it'll make your code better readable for yourself and others, so I strongly recommend doing so.

Comment: @MCEmperor i am appreciate you suggestion. i will do .

Comment: I couldn't help notice, both are private class with no default constructor!! Try adding default constructor and make the classes public. Gson uses reflection for acccessing the values and the name of the fields. In such cases, the access moodifiers play an important role.

Comment: For which devices you're getting this problem

Comment: So, I'd like to remove my answer down there, because it does not help you. I'd put it as a comment right here. But to solve your problem: please provide us your app (a simplest app which has the problem you've got) and provide a emulator in which we can reproduce the problem. Thanks.

Comment: In your code, there are some interesting things to point out:

Normally, I would always use List (one of the interfaces of ArrayList) as a type to store a list in it. ArrayList would be the specific type of the object passed there in.Variable names always small with camel case.
For your problem: - Gson does not convert null members by default. - Gson does not convert transient members by default.

Use GsonBuilder to customize a Gson instance for your case, for your need.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `ID` and `Records` in `ClassA` are null. Gson does not serialize nulls by default and actually has a method to enable serializing nulls, which I almost always enable:

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

I recommend keeping a static instance of a Gson around so you don't have to keep creating one each time you want to serialize.

If you don't want to serialize nulls, then you have some other options to fix your code, such as having null checks in the constructor of `ClassA`.

Comment: @Mr.AF you said you are viewing the JSON data in a server database. Can you confirm that any JSON data is "{}" by print statements or debug logging? It's possible that the error isn't in the code you posted and is in the way the json is uploaded or viewed.

Comment: see last section of question

Comment: @Mr.AF Ah I didn't see that. Can you tell us what values of ID and Records make it give "{}"?

Comment: see database records in question

Comment: @Mr.AF Yes, I see that the database contains a "{}". Can you locally debug and see what the values of ID and Records are when the json string equals "{}". Maybe debug all three values in a Toast, print statement, or log statement.

Comment: In my opinion this is closest to truth.

Answer (score 4):

Just my wild guess, I saw you mentioned in one of the comment that `ClassA` and `ClassB` are inner classes inside a fragment. So, maybe there's a few thing you  could try, if haven't already.

**First:** How about changing them into static inner class?

```
private static class ClassA {
    ...
}

private static class ClassB {
    ...
}
```

Having classes declared as inner class because no one else use it is okay, I did that sometimes too.  But non-static inner class kind of depended on its parent object instance, so declaring them static inner class is much safer, when it's just a simple bean/DTO classes.

**Second:**  Try fiddling around *Proguard* configuration about those classes

- Here's [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059888/android-proguard-keep-inner-class) about setting up *Proguard* to keep **inner classes** .
- Review the `-keep class <your packge name>.** { <fields>; }` part

**Third:**  Maybe try extracting those classes into a normal class just to narrow down the suspect area.

If it still doesn't work, then the problem probably lies somewhere else, maybe some specific build/version of the client mobile device or something.

Comment: Sounds good.your suggestions sounds practical and somehow might resolve problem . testing it takes times.i will test and feedback .

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<ClassB> Records= new ArrayList<>();
ClassA obj = new ClassA(null,Records);    
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),new Gson().toJson(obj 
),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In this case you rRecord arraylist is empty not null. try this checking

```
if(!Records.isEmpty()){ 
 // show toast
}
```

Comment: yea it's empty .as i said this condition is worse condition which might happen but as i said IDE says the worse condition never happens although i assumed to happens

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly catching a `JsonParseException` somewhere? [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/gson/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) sometimes causes trouble when a type is not registered with the `TypeAdapter`. Try commandeering the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` class and in the version that your project uses, replace every occurrence of

```
if (delegate == null) {
          throw new JsonParseException("cannot deserialize " + baseType + " subtype named "
              + label + "; did you forget to register a subtype?");
        }
```

With

```
if (delegate == null) {
    /*
    This class is commandeered from Google/Gson. The edit below was added so that if a type
    is not registered with the TypeAdapter, the app still works instead of throwing an
    exception and crash.
    */
    delegate = (TypeAdapter<R>) labelToDelegate.get(Constants.DEFAULT_TYPE); // "DefaultType" 
}
```

Comment: The hardness of resolving this problem was that there was not any exception ...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues();
 String data = builder.create().toJson(obj);
```

Comment: how does it help?what differences ?why?

Comment: It will help when your JSON has floating value and it try to covert in String

Comment: thanks.but all values are int and there isn't any float value.values are restored from content provider which its data type is INT.